# iPad app crashing on iPad 3, works fine on iPad 2, low memory warning

Tags: ios, crash

I have an iPad app that is working fine on iPad 2, but when trying to deploy on iPad 3 I it crashes and I get this message in XCode console window : 
Received memory warning.

Is this a hardware issue?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to give us more details on the crash, the memory warning is just send when your device is running low on memory. It is not the reason for the crash.

I would take a look at instruments specifically at memory allocations / leaks.